# As I do so as not to show the -1 in the Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Write a function to enter from the keyboard a series of numbers between 1 and 20 and save them in a list.In case of entering an out-of-range value the program will display an error message and ask for a new number.To finish loading you must enter -1.La function does not receive any parameters, and returns the loaded list (or empty, if the user did not enter anything) as the return value.

```
def funcion():
list = []
num = 0
while num != -1:
    num = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 20: "))
    while num > 20 :
        num = int(input("Please re-enter the number: "))
    list.append(num)
return lista
result = funcion()
print(result)
```

***My question is how I do not show the -1 in the list***

Comment: `if 0<num<20: do add to list` ?

Comment: Please reformat your code to valid Python code; Python is sensitive about indentation, and so are Python programmers.

Comment: What have you tried? This seems very low effort.

Comment: I don't think "lacks details or clarity" was a good enough reason to close this. There's enough of both to answer the question, as evidenced by the three answers.If StackOverflow want to close homework questions or those in which the questioner has made no effort, then they should add those to the list of reasons why questions can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to have an infinite loop and `break` out of it when the user enters -1:

```
def funcion():

    lista = []
    num = 0
    while True:
        num = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 20: "))
        while num > 20:
            num = int(input("Please re-enter the number: "))
        if num == -1:
            break
        else:
            lista.append(num)
    return lista

result = funcion()
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is saving the list except the last item like this:

```
return lista[:-1]
```

you can read more here:
https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

The minimal change to your code would just use the list slicing syntax to return all elements of `lista` apart from the last one:

```
return lista[:-1]
```

See [1] below. This is a pythonic way of writing the slightly more intuitive, but more verbose statement:

```
return lista[:len(lista)-1]
```

... which in turn is short for the even longer:

```
return lista[0:len(lista)-1]
```

You seem to be new to python. I really recommend looking up "list slicing" and "list comprehensions": if you already know a programming language that doesn't have these, once you learn these, you'll wonder how you ever did without them!

[1] http://knowledgehills.com/python/negative-indexing-slicing-stepping-comparing-lists.htm